# Remove rows based on search and find

Tags: vba, excel

I need this code to remove a row containing 0 as the left number in column D. I also need it remove a row with anything matching fl, 37941, or orlando in column B. However right now it will not remove anything in column D unless something matches in column B. So here is the code and what I need it to do.  Right now it will not remove anything in column D unless something matches in column B.  How can I fix it?

```
|A          |B          |C         |D

|           |orlando    |          |0        -Remove row

|           |           |          |37850    -Keep row

|           |Sorlando   |          |         -Remove row

|           |Ohio       |          |0434     -Remove row

|           |           |          |07856    -Remove row

|           |           |          |78560    -Keep row

|           |orlando    |          |         -Remove row

Sub Removal()
Dim i As Long, searchString As String

    For i = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        ' if a row is marked for deletion, delete it and continue.
      If Left(Range("D" & i), 1) = "0" Then
        Rows(i).Delete
          ' skip to next row
        GoTo NextRow
      End If

    searchString = LCase(Range("B" & i))

    If (InStr(1, searchString, "orlando") > 0) Or _
        (InStr(1, searchString, "fl") > 0) Or _
        (InStr(1, searchString, "37941") > 0) Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If

NextRow:
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I fix the code, because right now it will not remove anything in row D unless something matches in row B.

Comment: Just for clarification, columns go up and down, rows go across.  D and B are columns...  Also, avoid using GOTO statements, especially with what you're doing.  They are bad, bad things.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear on whether the values in column D are text masquerading as numbers or numbers with custom formatting that produces leading zeroes. I would recommend forcing `Left(Range("D" & i).Text, 1)` or an equivalent to make sure you cover both scenarios.

```
Sub Removal()
    Dim i As Long, searchString As String

    For i = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        ' if a row is marked for deletion, delete it and continue.
        searchString = LCase(Range("B" & i).Value)
        If Asc(Range("D" & i).Text) = 48 _
          Or CBool(InStr(1, searchString, "orlando", vbTextCompare)) _
          Or CBool(InStr(1, searchString, "fl", vbTextCompare)) _
          Or CBool(InStr(1, searchString, "37941", vbTextCompare)) Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

The VBA `Asc(...)` function returns the ASCII code for the single left-most character in a string. A zero is *48*. I know you are converting to lower case but I threw in the `vbTextCompare` parameter anyway. If the numeric values in column D are the results of worksheet formulas then you need to change `Range("D" & i).Text` to `Range("D" & i).Value` to use the formula's returned value as the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would approach this problem a bit differently, as follows:

1. Identify the range of cells that you want to evaluate. Load everything from A1 to D and whatever the last row is that you want to evaluate into the array.
2. Starting at the bottom of the array (called "arr" for clarity), determine if the value arr(x, 4) = "" or arr(x, 4) = 0. If it does, then delete the row in the spreadsheet corresponding to "x". (Note: If you use Option Base 0 or do not specify the base, you will need to delete row(x+1) in the spreadsheet.

**Note that you will have to process the deletions starting at the bottom of the spreadsheet, rather than at the top.** If you start at the top, you will end up offsetting the other rows by 1 for each row that is deleted, so every row after the first one that is removed will be a mistake.

Not sure if this is helpful or not. Let me know.